# Rails: are migrations needed here?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm working with an existing database that I have read-only rights.
I would like to define the relationships between tables (has_one, has_many, etc).
The following sites give examples of migrations to set-up these relationships:

http://www.theodinproject.com/ruby-on-rails/active-record-associations

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

My question is, does rails 'need' these migrations to setup the relations on an existing db...or will the definitions in the model files be sufficient?

thanks.

Comment: It completely depends on the existing DB. If the existing DB has a decent schema with primary keys and foreign keys (where needed) you can simply setup the relations in your models. However with zero knowledge of the existing DB there is no way we actually can say yes or no.

Answer (score 0):

Please check if your database already has external keys (fields like `order_id`).

If it does not, you need to write migrations before defining your associations. If you are using Rails 4, they would look like this:

```
class AddGroupToPeople < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
   add_reference :people, :group, index: true
   add_foreign_key :people, :groups
  end
end
```

Please use this guide: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html